# Elegant way to purposefully charge more gas in a smart contract

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate

I am trying to run tests to see how much a smart contract will cost, but since I am in my research period, I have to make some assumptions on how my smart contract will be developed. I would like to write some functions into my smart contract that cost set amounts of gas. For example, I'd like to create a function

`function cost200kgas() public {}`

Which when called, costs 200,000 gas. Is there an elegant way to write this code into a Solidity smart contract?

Comment: you want an elegant way to spend 200k gas or do you want to know the cost of execution? if it is the later, run a trace and it will give you detailed expenditure per opcode

Comment: I want an elegant way to spend 200k gas or even better a function to spend an arbitrary number of gas thats input as an argument

Comment: then you need to allocate memory or maybe memory copy in a loop to get better precision. using assembly language

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Nulik, I was hoping there would be a better way but that makes sense